# Jquery does not complete whole string

Tags: jquery

Basically I'm creating a simple rollover feature. Rollover a section and it reveals more info. It is all working fine except that I want to close the open div when the user clicks on a div with a class of "close." I have a string of things that need to happen but for some reason only one is firing. Here's a sample of my HTML:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="truck"><img src="eVie.png" width="637" height="280" alt="Evie" /></div>
<div class="marker a">
<div class="content a inactive"><img src="solarpanel.jpg" width="240" height="205" alt="Solar Panels" /><div class="close"></div>
  <h2>Solar Panels</h2>
  <p>Here Comes The Sun: These solar panels capture light and heat from the sun to power exhibits when I’m out visiting around town.</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="marker b">
<div class="content b inactive"><img src="tailpipe.jpg" width="240" height="205" alt="Tailpipe Area" />
  <h2>Tailpipe Area</h2>
  <p>No tailpipe, no fumes. That’s how I roll.</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="marker c">
<div class="content c inactive"><img src="plug.jpg" width="240" height="205" alt="Plug" />
  <h2>Plug</h2>
  <p>Not An Ordinary Plug: Big trucks need more energy. To get all the energy I need, I have to have a bigger plug and a special outlet!</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

You can see on .content.a that I have my close div like this:

```
<div class="close"></div>
```

Here is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".marker").hover(
function(){
$(this).children(".content.inactive").addClass("show");  
$(this).children(".content.inactive").animate({width: 155}, "fast");     
 }
 ,
 function(){
$(this).children(".content.inactive").animate({width: 5, height: 23}, "fast");
$(this).children(".content.inactive").removeClass("show");       
 }
 );
 $(".content").click(
function(){
$(this).removeClass("inactive");
$(this).addClass("active");  
$(this).animate({width: 435, height: 205}, "fast"); 
$(".inactive").addClass("disabled");
$(".disabled").removeClass("inactive"); 
$(".disabled").parent().addClass("dim");
$("#truck img").addClass("dim");
  }
  );
  $(".content.active").click(
  function(){
  $(".content").animate({width: 5, height: 23}, "fast");
  $(".disabled").addClass("inactive");
$(".inactive").removeClass("disabled"); 
$(".inactive").parent().removeClass("dim");
$("#truck img").removeClass("dim"); 
$(".active").addClass("inactive");
$(".show").removeClass("show");
$(".active").removeClass("active"); 
  });
  $(".content").click(function(){ return false; });
  $(document).on("click", function() { $(".content").animate({width: 5, height: 23}, "fast");

$(".disabled").addClass("inactive");
$(".inactive").removeClass("disabled"); 
$(".inactive").parent().removeClass("dim");
$("#truck img").removeClass("dim"); 
$(".active").addClass("inactive");
$(".show").removeClass("show");
$(".active").removeClass("active"); 
   });

   $(".close").click(
   function(){ 
$(".show").removeClass("show");
$(".content.disabled").parent().removeClass("dim");
    $(".inactive").parent().removeClass("dim");
$("#truck img").removeClass("dim"); 
$(".active").addClass("inactive");
$(".show").removeClass("show");
$(".active").removeClass("active");
   });

   });
```

The last portion of that is where I'm trying to execute a string when you click on .close. However, no matter what I put there only the removeClass("show") fires.

Here's what I have so far: http://stlenergy.org/evie/

HELP! I'm assuming something else in my code is interfering with this command but I can't figure it out. Thanks in advance for any help!